# how to write JUnit test cases for API's which expects HTTP requests

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I have a API that takes a **javax.jcr.Session** as input and does some work.So how do i generate JUnit test cases for this API.How do I create HTTP request object and jcr session from that.

Comment: If your input parameter are interfaces so you could provide your own implementation of them, witch by the way you could easier feed with test data. If normal classes so you could extend them an override relevant methods for oyour unit test. `javax.jcr.Session` is an interface: http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/Session.html

Comment: i am actually looking for some framework that could generate a HTTP request object for me.Ya I can implement the interface but I am trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, just use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). For me it's one of the simplest ways of getting complex objects that you need just to test your stuff.

You can do something like:

```
Session mockSession = Mockito.mock(Session.class);
someApiMethod(mockSession);
```

You can check out the [documentation at the Mockito site](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html).